# If $1, \omega, \omega^2$ are cube roots, show that $(2-\omega)(2-\omega^2)(2-\omega^{19})(2-\omega^{23})=49$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, roots-of-unity

If $1, \omega, \omega^2$ are cube roots, how to show that

$$
(2-\omega)
 \left(2-\omega^2\right)
 \left(2-\omega^{19}\right)
 \left(2-\omega^{23}\right) = 49$$

I really don't know how to start. Help!

Comment: Write the exponents $23$ and $19$ modulo $3$ and use the fact that they are cube roots.

Comment: do you mean cube root of unity?

Comment: What does this have to do with differential equations?

Comment: @Allawonder nothing, OP is new and looked for some tag with the word **equation** in it, likely

Answer (score 2):

Clearly $\omega^3=1$ and $1+\omega+\omega^2=0$. So, the problem reduces to:

$$(2-\omega)(2-\omega^2)(2-\omega)(2-\omega^{2})=(2-\omega)^2(2-\omega^2)^2=(4+\omega^2-4\omega)(4+\omega^4-4\omega^2)$$
$$=(4+\omega^2-4\omega)(4+\omega-4\omega^2)=16+4\omega-16\omega^2+4\omega^2+1-4\omega-16\omega-4\omega^2+16$$
$$=33+-16(\omega+\omega^2)=\boxed{49}$$

since $\omega+\omega^2=-1$.

Comment: +1, took the liberty to edit the equation for better readability

Comment: If this answer was helpful for you, please consider clicking the checkmark. Glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

Using modular arhitmetic and the fact that $\omega^3=1$, we can write:
$$(2-\omega)
 \left(2-\omega^2\right)
 \left(2-\omega^{19}\right)
 \left(2-\omega^{23}\right) =(5-2\omega^2-2\omega)\cdot(5-2\omega^2-2\omega)$$
Now, rearranging this expression and using the fact that $1+\omega+\omega^2=0$, we arrive at:
$$(2-\omega)
 \left(2-\omega^2\right)
 \left(2-\omega^{19}\right)
 \left(2-\omega^{23}\right) = 49$$

Comment: @Ashe Danni: if this answet has been useful, maybe a $+1$ or a favourite answer?

Answer (score 1):

Since $\omega^3=1$ and $\omega^2+\omega+1=0$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
(2-\omega)(2-\omega^2)(2-\omega^{19})(2-\omega^{23})
&=
(2-\omega)(2-\omega^2)(2-\omega^{1})(2-\omega^{2})
\\&=
((2-\omega)(2-\omega^2))^2
\\&=
(-2 \omega^2 - 2 \omega + 5)^2
\\&=
(-2(\omega^2 + \omega) + 5)^2
\\&=
(-7)^2
=49
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Clearly we have that $1, \omega, \omega^2$ are the roots of the polynomial $p(x):=x^3-1$. 
Therefore, it follows that
$$p(x)=(x-1)(x-\omega)(x-\omega^2)$$
and that $\omega^3=1$. Now,
$$\begin{align}(2-\omega)(2-\omega^2)(2-\omega^{19})(2-\omega^{23})&=(2-1)(2-\omega)(2-\omega^2)(2-1)(2-\omega)(2-\omega^2)\\&=p(2)^2\\&=49\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $\omega,\omega^{2}$ are the roots of $f(x)=x^{2}+x+1$,

$$
(2-\omega)(2-\omega^{2})(2-\omega^{19})(2-\omega^{23}) =\left(f(2)\right)^{2}=49
$$